# how to disable default hover and click effects of material-ui cardActionArea

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

as you can see in here https://material-ui.com/components/cards
the card sample with a lizard photo in it. as you hover over the cardActionArea it will get darker(lighter) based on the theme and when you click on the card the picture will get lighter(darker) starting from around the mouse pointer.
now I have two questions :
1- how can I change the color of the click effect ? for example I want the photo to get red (change hue ) when user clicks on it
2- I have implemented my own hover effect that when you hover, the card will go up a little bit(codes below). how can I disable the default hover effect that changes the color of the picture ?

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {
        width: 345,
        margin: 5,
        '&:hover': {
            transform: 'translateY(-5px) !important'
        },
    },
    media: {
        maxHeight: 350,
        marginBottom:-3
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to disable the pointer-events, which will stop the default hover effects (note this will also stop the onClick events as well, as it will disable all mouse events):

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {
        width: 345,
        margin: 5,
        '&:hover': {
            pointerEvents: 'none',
            transform: 'translateY(-5px) !important'
        },
    },
    media: {
        maxHeight: 350,
        marginBottom:-3
    },
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. as you said it will stop onClick events and I need that. I need to know which css property will change by default in mui hover so that I can change its Value myself and overwrite that

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question. Are you asking what css properties change by default when hovering over a specific Material-UI component? For that, you'll have to use your console and browser debugger tools to see the css generated by Material-UI classes.

Comment: hover is the event you want to prevent, so this would have to be moved directly to `root`, instead of the pseudo class.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const {
  Card,
  CardActionArea,
  CardActions,
  CardContent,
  CardMedia,
  Button,
  Typography,
  makeStyles
} = MaterialUI;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    maxWidth: 345,
    transition: theme.transitions.create("transform", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeInOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.standard
    }),
    "&:hover": {
      transform: "translateY(-5px)"
    }
  },
  focus: {
    "&&&": {
      opacity: 0
    }
  },
  ripple: {
    color: "red"
  }
}));

function ImgMediaCard() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Card className={classes.root}>
      <CardActionArea
        classes={{ focusHighlight: classes.focus }}
        TouchRippleProps={{ className: classes.ripple }}
      >
        <CardMedia
          component="img"
          alt="Contemplative Reptile"
          height="140"
          image="https://material-ui.com/static/images/cards/contemplative-reptile.jpg"
          title="Contemplative Reptile"
        />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
            Lizard
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
            Lizards are a widespread group of squamate reptiles, with over 6,000
            species, ranging across all continents except Antarctica
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
      <CardActions>
        <Button size="small" color="primary">
          Share
        </Button>
        <Button size="small" color="primary">
          Learn More
        </Button>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<ImgMediaCard />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@latest/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@latest/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@latest/babel.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" />
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**How to disable default hover and click effects of material-ui CardActionArea** 
We can also disable the default hover and click effects from CardActionArea, by making it a styled component:

```
const styledcardactionarea = styled(CardActionArea)(({theme}) => `
    .muicardactionarea-focushighlight {
        background: transparent;
    }
`);
```